# Event Photography Display Software

Tags: photography

I'm looking for software for displaying pictures taken at sports events so that customers can select photos to be printed on the day, this has to work in a disconnected scenario. Use case: the photographer hands the SDCARD to the operative after each event, the operative uploads and categorizes the photos, the customers browse on portable terminals and select, pay and print. (software does not have to automate pay and print)